# Condition as a Variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to pass a variable as a condition '<,>,+,=' in SQL but not sure the right way and cant find anything online to help me.

Basically, I have information where I need to see a buy and sell side on an invoice and don't want two separate procedures for it.

Example would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Details
WHERE Credit @Direction 0
```

@Direction could be <,> or =

Comment: you need dynamic sql for this, there are plenty examples for this

Comment: Any chance you can show us more of your procedure? Maybe we can give input on another approach to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like that no. There are a couple of options open to you though.

The first would be to use several `OR` expressions.

```
DECLARE @Direction varchar(2);

SET @Direction = '=';

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (YourColumn = 0 AND @Direction = '=')
   OR (YourColumn > 0 AND @Direction = '>')
   OR (YourColumn < 0 AND @Direction = '<')
   OR (YourColumn != 0 AND @Direction = '!=')
   OR (YourColumn >= 0 AND @Direction = '>=')
   OR (YourColumn <= 0 AND @Direction = '<=');
```

This, however, is probably going to suffer horribly on performance.

Thus, the other option would be to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Direction nvarchar(2);
SET @Direction = N'=';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM YourTable' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'WHERE YourColumn ' + @Direction + N'0;';
PRINT @SQL; --This is your best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

It's, however, incredibly important you don't increase the length of the value `@Direction`, or you'll option yourself up to injection.

If you're passing a value, instead of always comparing to `0` then use something like this. *Edit: Also added a validation check on the value of the Direction parameter and `RAISERROR` if it isn't valid):

```
DECLARE @Direction nvarchar(2), @i int;
SET @Direction = N'!'; --Intentionally incorrect
SET @i = 0;


IF @Direction NOT IN (N'=',N'>',N'<',N'!=',N'>=',N'<=') BEGIN

    DECLARE @Error nvarchar(500) = N'Direction parameter has an invalid value (''' + @Direction + N'''). Accepted values are =,<,>,!=,>= and <=.';         
    RAISERROR(@Error, 11, -1);

END ELSE BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'FROM YourTable' + NCHAR(10) +
               N'WHERE YourColumn ' + @Direction + N' @si';
    PRINT @SQL; --This is your best friend
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@si int', @si = @i;

END
```

Comment: For the injection warning +1

Comment: I see far too many answers on SO that are open to injection @GuidoG that it terrifies me.

Comment: Rather than relying on the fact that two characters aren't enough to do injection, I'd probably prefer actually checking the value of `@Direction` against all possibilities in this case. As a bonus, this gives you clear errors if an invalid value is passed accidentally, rather than a cryptic error about invalid SQL. In general, checking the input for all possibilities to prevent injection isn't possible, of course, but in this case it is.

Comment: @JeroenMostert updated with your idea. Very nice tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use EXEC to achieve the same. e.g.

```
Declare @Direction nvarchar(10) 
Declare @Query nvarchar(1000)

Set @Direction = '<'

Set @query = 'SELECT * FROM Details WHERE Credit ' + @Direction + '0'

EXEC sp_executsql @query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic SQL . In Procedure you have to prepare the query and execute SP by passing the @direction. Something like below.

```
Create proc test 
@Direction varchar(2)
AS
(
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL='SELECT * FROM Details WHERE Credit '+@direction+ ' 0'
Exec (@SQL)
)

Exec test '>'
```

Comment: You also need to pass the value as second parameter so it does not always have to compare with ' 0'